# Angular applications architecture

Tags: angular, architecture

I have been thinking about the architecture of an angular application as opposed to the architecture of a .Net/Java application.

In .Net/Java - if you have two classes (analog to angular components) and you want to manage them both, e.g see state of both of them and make decisions, then both of these classes are controlled by another class (that either creates/injected with these two classes).

In a .Net/Java application the highest level class (those closer to the composition root) control the more high-level flow and are responsible for orchestrating their dependencies.

I'm opposing that with what I see happening in Angular applications (which I am new at) - in angular we have components which are just "floating around", there is no composition root and a tree like structure of dependencies (or rather it's rather flat), under the module there are all the components in that module.

Although there are "nested components" it's much more "plug-and-play" in the view, and it's not something that allows to orchestrate some lower level components.

**The Question** : What is the proper way to orchestrate angular components ?

It's true that I can pass data from one component to another by a shared service or by the route, but this is very different and limiting the reusability (as far as I have been able to see) as opposed to being able to have some higher level component responsible for the orchestration

Comment: use state management techniques to share data across components

Answer (score 1):

There is a component hierarchy but as you said, it is composed using nested components. The AppComponent is the root component, so it can provide orchestration for your application. (But not really best for a piece of the application.)

There is also a route hierarchy, so you can do some orchestration using parent and child routes. For example, I created a edit component with a route that is a parent route to its tab components. So the edit component orchestrates the interaction between all of the edit "tabs" and their associated components.

And as you mentioned, services are there to share data and functionality between any of the components.